# Why does Spyne complex result have both Response and Result levels?

Tags: soap, spyne

I'm trying to return a Complex result from a spyne/SOAP/HTTP application but I'm seeing the expected 'CommandResponse' level but also an unexpected 'CommandResult' level (in the XML) before my data starts.

I've not create a 'CommandResult' object anywhere so where does this come from and how can I stop it?  Examples such as...
http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_soap_example.asp
...show the CommandResponse but no CommandResult level.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this, you want to use...

@srpc(..., _returns=[type1, type2...], _out_variable_names=["name1", "name2"...])

Spyne will now create a result which has the required CommandResponse level with your three fields immediately below it i.e. you have not had to create a ComplexModel object which implicitly created the CommandResults level.  The useful ref is here:
http://spyne.io/docs/2.10/reference/decorator.html
However there are not really any examples.

Answer (score 0):

That's because wrapped functions are the default in Spyne. Wrapped functions are:

1) Easier to use than bare functions, which can only accept and return max. one type.

2) Any Xml type should be serializable using one single root node, as per the Xml standard.

If you want to have return documents similar to the ones in w3schools, you must pass `_body_style='bare'` to the `@rpc` decorator.

However, it's only recommended for compatibility reasons and should be avoided if possible.

PS: Papadeltasierra's answer is also correct -- that's exactly what the bare mode does behind the scenes.